# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when trying to iterate over a list of running process

Tags: python, windows, taskkill

I am using Python in Windows. I am trying to kill a windows running process if it is already running but i get below error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I import the following modules:

```
import os
import subprocess
from time import sleep
```

Then below my code:

```
s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
if "myProcess.exe" in s:
    print('myProcess.exe is currently running. Killing...')
    os.system("taskkill /f /im myProcess.exe")
    sleep(0.5)
```

The error happens just in the conditional when trying to compare if the process myProcess.exe is in the list s.

Comment: In which line is the error? Post the full error message including traceback.

Comment: @kindall just in the "if" when trying to compare if the myProcess is in the list (in this case s)

Comment: @Axe319 your solution works so if you post this as answer I will accept it. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) returns a `bytes` object. The error you are seeing occurs when you check for membership of a string in `bytes`.

For example:

```py
'foo' in b'bar'
```

results in:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

You can fix this in 2 different ways, by passing in `text=True` to `subprocess.check_output` or by simply using a `bytes` object for membership checking.

```py
s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True, text=True)
```

or:

```py
if b"myProcess.exe" in s:
    # do something
```